# Командная строка. Находясь в "с\какая-то папка\какая-то папка" можно перейти в "д\другая папка" одной командной?

Tags: командная-строка

я в курсе, что можно написать
d:
cd "путь". но как одной командой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
cd /d "д:\другая папка"
```

---

Внеклассное чтение: [исторический экскурс по понятию текущего каталога от Реймонда Чена](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101011-00/?p=12563).

Comment: о, да. спасибо.

Comment: @OlegBrony: Пожалуйста!